# How can I assign pre-determined codes (1,2,3, etc,) to a JSON-type column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, redash

I'm extracting a table of 2000+ rows which are park details. One of the columns is JSON type. [Image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raZOd.png)

We have about 15 attributes like this and we also have a documentation of pre-determined codes assigned to each attribute.

Each row in the extracted table has a different set of attributes that you can see in the image. Right now, I have `cast(parks.services AS text) AS "details"` to get all the attributes for a particular park or extract just one of them using the code below:

```
CASE
       WHEN cast(parks.services AS text) LIKE '%uncovered%' THEN '2'
       WHEN cast(parks.services AS text) LIKE '%{covered%' THEN '1' END AS "details"
```

This time around, I need to extract these attributes by assigning them the codes. As an example, let's just say

1. Park 1 - {covered, handicap_access, elevator} to be {1,3,7}
2. Park 2 - {uncovered, always_open, handicap_access} to be {2,5,3}

I have thought of using subquery to pre-assign the codes, but I cannot wrap my head around JSON operators - in fact, I don't know how to extract them on 2000+ rows.

It would be helpful if someone could guide me in this topic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really think about normalizing your tables. Don't store arrays. You should add a mapping table to map the parks and the attribute codes. This makes everything much easier and more performant.

---

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2265cd2df296c7578db01c0bf1975e64)

```
SELECT
    t.name,
    array_agg(c.code ORDER BY elems.index) as codes             -- 3
FROM mytable t,
    unnest(attributes) WITH ORDINALITY as elems(value, index)   -- 1
JOIN codes c ON c.name = elems.value                            -- 2
GROUP BY t.name
```

1. Extract the array elements into one record per element. Add the `WITH ORDINALITY` to save the original order.
2. Join your codes on the elements
3. Create code arrays. To ensure the correct order, you can use the `index` values created by the `WITH ORDINALITY` clause.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I don't have extensive experience working with tables, so I mistook the form. I see that the values are an ARRAY and not JSON type.

Comment: Adapted the answer. The algorithm (and first recommendation!) remains the same, just changed `jsonb_array_elements_text` to `unnest` and `jsonb_agg` to `array_agg`.